# Why does Array.prototype.map ignore empty slots in a sparse array whereas Array.prototype.join does not?

Tags: javascript, arrays

The [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function works as expected when applied on an array with `undefined` values:

```js
const array = [undefined, undefined, undefined];
console.log(array.map(x => 'x')); // prints ["x", "x", "x"]
```

However, when using `map` on a sparse array with empty slots, it does not map them to 'x' as in the previous example. Instead, it returns `undefined` values:

```js
const array = [,,,];
console.log(array.map(x => 'x')); // prints [undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

Even if we have an array with a mix of empty slots and actual values, only the latter ones are mapped:

```js
const array = [,'a',,'b',];
console.log(array.map(x => 'x')); // prints [undefined, "x", undefined, "x"]
```

In contrast, I noticed [`Array.prototype.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) works on empty slots:

```js
const array = [,,,,];
console.log(array.join('x')); // prints "xxx"
```

Why does `join` treat empty slots as valid elements, but `map` does not?

Furthermore, in the [join documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), they mention that if an element is `undefined`, `null` or an `empty array []`, it is converted to an empty string. They do not mention empty slots, but it seems they are also converting them to an empty string.

Is it then a problem in the MDN documentation? And why not having `join` also ignore empty slots in the same way `map` does? It seems to be either a problem in the documentation or in the implementation of `join`.

Comment: Because that's how it's defined to work. It handles sparse arrays by not going through the empty slots. Same behaviour as any of the array iteration methods: `some`, `reduce`, `filter`, etc.

Comment: It's an odd behaviour. Do you have any reference about this? Thanks for input

Comment: From the docs you linked: "map calls a provided callback function once for each element in an array, in order, and constructs a new array from the results. callback is invoked **only for indexes of the array which have assigned values** (including undefined)."

Comment: @AlbertoTrindadeTavares: just check what `Object.keys` returns for a sparse array `[,,]` vs what it returns for an array with actual undefined values `[undefined, undefined, undefined]`.

Comment: the "assigned" part being the operative word. Something like `[,,,]` has no assigned values, but `[undefined,undefined,undefined]` has assigned values that happen to have the value `undefined`.

Comment: I'm not sure why it would be odd. If you have a sparse array of objects and want to do something like `objs.map(o => o.id)` you don't need null guards and you don't change the number of the results, either. It seems perfectly logical. And my reference is literally the specs.You can check the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Description) which describes that and links to relevant specs, too.

Comment: I see the point of all of you. The `map` documentation lacks explicit mention to empty slots. Actually, in general, there's very little documentation around them. But yes, it makes sense indeed.

Comment: What do you mean by "little documentation"? There is a full spec https://tc39.es/ecma262/2019/#sec-array.prototype.map

Comment: I mean documentation about empty slots in general, not map specifically.

Comment: @AlbertoTrindadeTavares it says: "map calls a provided callback function **once for each element in an array**" - emphasis right there in the link. Following that paragraph it explicitly says "It is not called for missing elements of the array; that is: indexes that have never been set; which have been deleted; or which have never been assigned a value." which literally just enumerates all possibilities for an empty slot. It seems quite explicit to me.

Comment: @VLAZ Agreed. An empty slot is clearly a missing element which has never been assigned a value.

Comment: It could also be a slot that was assigned a value then the index was `delete`d.

Comment: I edited my question a bit because I noticed that `Array.prototype.join` actually considers empty slots as elements. Found this at least interesting and possibly inconsistent.

Comment: Again, the answer to your modified question is simply "because that's what the specs say". So, it's not inconsistent to follow the rules laid down for how the algorithm has to behave.

Comment: I am more distressed by Your last example, where five undefined literals are joined only to four...

Comment: Oh, @deblocker actually `[,,,,]` is 4 empty slots, the last comma is just a trailing comma. This is equivalent to `[<empty slot>, <empty slot>, <empty slot>, <empty slot>]`

Comment: yes, I am aware, JavaScript ignores trailing commas in arrays and moreover if more than one trailing comma is used, an elision is produced (???!!!). But anyway, that example it looks to me terrific and frightening  ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`join` attempts to produce a serialized representation of the array. `map` produces a projection of the elements of an array through some transforming function.

With `map`, it is possible to say: "As you step through the array, if you encounter an index that has no property, leave that property similarly unset in the output array." For all existing properties, output indices will still correspond to their input indices, and the missing properties are skipped in both the input and output.

With `join`'s string output, we can't really do this. If we join `[,'a',,'b',]`, an output of `,a,,b,` is the best way to represent this. An output that skips missing properties -- i.e., `a,b` -- would be hugely misleading, appearing to be a length-2 array with elements at indices `0` and `1`.

Unlike `map`, which can produce an array with variously present or absent properties, `join` is stuck rendering a string output, which cannot readily distinguish missing vs. empty properties in its output without hugely misleading results.

For completeness, here are the actual ECMAScript-specified behaviors where the function loops through the input array (in each, `k` is the loop variable):

**[Array.prototype.join](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.join)**

> Repeat, while *k* < *len*
>
> - If *k* > 0, set *R* to the string-concatenation of *R* and *sep*.
> - Let *element* be ? Get(*O*, ! ToString(*k*)).
> - If *element* is **undefined** or **null**, let *next* be the empty String; otherwise, let *next* be ? ToString(*element*).
> - Set *R* to the string-concatenation of *R* and *next*.
> - Increase *k* by 1.

**[Array.prototype.map](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.map)**

> Repeat, while *k* < *len*
>
> - Let *Pk* be ! ToString(*k*).
> - Let *kPresent* be ? HasProperty(*O*, *Pk*).
> - If *kPresent* is **true**, then
>
>   - Let *kValue* be ? Get(*O*, *Pk*).
>   - Let *mappedValue* be ? Call(*callbackfn*, *T*, « *kValue*, *k*, *O* »).
>   - Perform ? CreateDataPropertyOrThrow(*A*, *Pk*, *mappedValue*).
> - Increase *k* by 1.

Even if you don't know how to read all of this, it's plain to see that `map` includes a `HasProperty` check in the second loop step. `join` explicitly says "If element is `undefined` or `null`, let *next* be the empty String." `Get(O, ! ToString(k))` is a usual property lookup which, for ordinary objects, yields `undefined` when a property is absent, so the "If element is `undefined`" case applies.

It's worth noting that the MDN documentation simplifies its information in order to focus on the most common cases instead of adhering to rigorous completeness. (I would say that sparse arrays are an uncommon case.) In particular, they say that an empty array will serialize to the empty string, which is true. This is true in general for any value that has a `toString` function which returns an empty string:

```
["foo", { toString: a=>""}, "bar"].join()
```

This will produce the output `foo,,bar`.

Comment: Thanks for your very detailed answer! I was wondering whether join should skip `Set R to the string-concatenation of R and next` in case the element is an empty slot, but the current implementation makes sense, also considering what you wrote before. Will just a bit longer before marking this answer as accepted (in case other people try to answer), but will most likely accept yours :)

Answer (score 6):

#### If you're here NOT for excerpts from tutorials, but for practical ways to get array methods behave in desired way, consider the following:

---

```js
const array = [,,,];
console.log([...array].map(x => 'x'));
```

...if you need resulting array of initial size, or

```js
const array = [,'a',,'b',]
console.log([...array].filter(Boolean).map(x => x+'x'));
```

...if you need to *skip* empty slots

Comment: question is "Why does this work this way" your answer doesn't cover that and answers a different question instead.

Comment: @VLAZ : Personally I see more value in solution you might use to overcome the issue, than in long-winded discourse around a straightforward sentence from the very first chapter of reference docs

Comment: There is no issue here that I'm aware of. `.map` works exactly as it should and exactly like all the array iteration methods in that it skips missing slots. So, it's working as intended. If somebody faces an issue with that, then they can ask about it but the question wasn't "I want to map over missing slots". Yes, I agree the question makes little sense since it links to the documentation describing the behaviour and asks why does this happen but it just means there is not much to really answer: "Why does X do Y given the documentation <where X is defined as producing Y>"

Answer (score 2):

This is how JS handles sparse arrays. Consider:

```js
> let a = [,,,,,]
> a
[ <5 empty items> ]
> let b = [undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined]
> b
[ undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined ]
> let c = [,,'x',,]
> c
[ <2 empty items>, 'x', <1 empty item> ]
```

Empty items do not actually take up any space (beyond some overhead).